What syllables can cause Sokuon?
I started studying kanji and found out about sokuon. But I have noticed that other than the last つ of the first syllable, there are other syllables that also can cause sokuon.
What I want to know is which syllables can cause sokuon to occur other than the last つ.

I imagine you've encountered 学 (がく) > 学校 (がっこう) if you've studied enough to encounter the word sokuon

As I understand, theくsound in 学校 becomes a small っ because it is difficult to pronounce K sounds one after the other, but I thought proper sokuon only happened when the last syllable was つ.

I'm not sure I understand the distinction you're making between "proper" sokuon and presumably other kinds of sokuon. The pronunciation represented by "a small っ" in any context is called sokuon, no?

I mean I thought く becomes a small っ out of convenience in some words, while the others are more consistent in their use.

"Doesn't this only happen when the last syllable of the first word is つ?" What makes you think this is the case? Both the high vowels /i/ and /u/ are susceptible to resulting in sokuon. It's just that /u/ is more common, but it's not the only one. Make no mistake, the small っ is a mere spelling, it does not imply the original sound must contain the vowel /u/.

That's what I want to know. I want to know which syllables cause sokuon to occur other than the last つ.

As far as I can tell, ち,き,つ,く. The historial ふ, now う, rarely occurs.
ち/つ + /s, t, k, h/ > /ss, tt, kk, pp/;
き/く + /k/ > /kk/; rarely き/く + /h/ > /pp/, for example in 北方;
historical ふ + /s, t, k, h/ > /ss, tt, kk, pp/, for example in 十歳

Oh man, thank you so much. I was very confused about this whole thing.

@Elpanasilver, the outcome of this commenting thread seems to make sense and seems like it would be useful for others visiting this site.  Could you edit your question post to include your rephrasing here in the comments?  "I want to know which syllables cause sokuon to occur other than the last つ."  I think that will make this question post clearer and easier to find for others who might have the same question.

@Vun-HughVaw, could you convert your comment to an answer post?  That will make this a proper Q&A JSE post, and it will be easier for future readers.

contraction of certain syllables into gemination (the sound change is called [促音化]{そくおんか}) is something that happens all the time in Japanese, from the ～て form of verbs, to the prefix ぶっ～ from ぶち～ as in ぶっ飛ばす, or randomly in certain compounds like [取]{と}っ[手]{て} from [取]{と}り[手]{て}. what I'm describing in this answer is how sokuonka affects [漢語]{かんご}, Sino-Japanese words with on'yomi readings. sokuonka in native terms will usually be spelled out in hiragana for you (exceptions like [切手]{きって} do exist, but there's not a lot of them), so you don't have to guess when it happens.
～ち and ～つ endings will practically always contract to ～っ if they're before a k-, t- (incl. つ and ち), s- (incl. し) or h- (incl. ふ) sound:

[日]{にっ}[記]{き} < にち + き
[出]{しゅっ}[発]{ぱつ} < しゅつ + はつ
(here the /h/ shifts to a /p/ because it's doubled; this also happens if it's after an ん, as in [先]{せん}[輩]{ぱい}.)
[一]{いっ}[生]{しょう} < いち + しょう
same for [必死]{ひっし}, [喝采]{かっさい}, [失笑]{しっしょう}, and a lot more

～く will only contract before /k/, as in [学校]{がっこう} and [国歌]{こっか}. only in counters, you can see ～く contract before a /h/ sound, as in [六杯]{ろっぱい} and [百本]{ひゃっぽん} but this isn't a normal thing that happens in other words.
～き usually doesn't contract. 的確 is てきかく. but in a few words, you get a contraction, like with 石 (せき > せっ) in [石鹸]{せっけん} and [石棺]{せっかん} 'stone coffin, sarcophagus'.
lastly, sometimes a reading that doesn't have a final "hard" consonant will trigger a contraction (with a change in the vowel), as in [合戦]{かっせん} < こう + せん, or [十歳]{じゅっさい} from じゅう + さい. this is because historically the [合]{こう > かっ} in 合戦 was pronounced kap, and kap-sen contracted into kassen, while if it was by itself, it evolved to kapu, then kafu > kau > kō. same process for 十 as in 十歳, which was zip, and zip-sai became zissai (= jissai) — later, it evolved to modern jussai by analogy with jū, while standalone zip became zipu, ziu and then zyū (= jū). the contraction of 十 before one of /k s t h/ in counters is very common, as in [十回]{じゅっかい} and [二十分]{にじゅっぷん}, so watch out for that.
